# crystal reports not work in client machine with "error '713' Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a Crystal 8.5 Report in a VB6 application.
The crystal report not run on client machine and get error

> "Run-time error '713' Application-defined or object-defined error".

But the crystal report work on programmer machine.

how to run the crystal report successfully on client machine ?

With Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Crystal Reports is a separate control (OCX) file that needs to be packaged together with your application (EXE) because your client doesn't have it installed on his machine. That's why you need to create an installation package.

Have you tried packaging the application in the form of an installation kit with the "Package and Deployment Wizard"  in your Visual Studio installation? That should include all dependencies necessary to run on client machines.

Comment: my application no have packaging or  installation . just exe file only.

Comment: Crystal Reports is a separate control (OCX) file that needs to be packaged together with your application because your client doesn't have it installed on his machine! That's why you need to create an installation package!

Comment: I used crystal report 8.5 then my crystal report in my application is worked . I can't understand why I'm working on Crystal Reportز

Comment: Crystal Reports 8.5 needs to be packaged along with your EXE when you send it to your client. I don't know how to be more clear... You should have an application called "Package & Deployment Wizard" in your Visual Studio installation. You need to use it if you want your program to run on your client's machine!

Comment: Crystal Report is worked in client machine. thanks VanGogh Gaming to help me.

Comment: Ok, than maybe choose my answer as the solution to this question?

Comment: @mohammednaseralla it might have worked BY LUCK on that other machine. The file which is a dependency probably was already installed and registered there. VB6 dependencies are normally installed *globally* which means that one program can affect another. What VanGogh is saying is 100% correct.  You should look on the working machine and see if you can find that OCX there already.

Comment: @StayOnTarget As far as I can understand from his English, he fixed it by installing Crystal Reports 8.5 on the other machine. That's one way to do it I guess...